# How to display kanban style tile in form view?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

I have an one2many image field that currently shows images in a tabular style. What I want to do is to show it in a card style like a kanban card.

This is how my current view is: [image: Current view]
  And this is the view I want: [image: Current view]
 This is my current code:

```
    class VariantsLines(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.variants.lines'

    product_image_360_ids = fields.One2many('product.image.360', 'product_tmpl_id', string='Images')
    display_360_image = fields.Boolean(string='Display 360 Image')


class ProductImage360(models.Model):
    _name = 'product.image.360'
    _order = 'sequence'

    name = fields.Char(string='Name', readonly=False)
    image = fields.Binary(string='Image', attachment=True, readonly=False)
    product_tmpl_id = fields.Many2one('product.template', string='Related Product', copy=True)
    sequence = fields.Integer(string="Sequence", readonly=False)

view.xml

    <field name="inherit_id" ref="jewellery.view_product_variants_lines_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//form" position="inside">
                    <div>
                        <group>
                            <field name="display_360_image"/>
                        </group>

                        <group string="Images for 360 view" attrs="{'invisible': [('display_360_image', '=', False)]}">
                            <field name="product_image_360_ids" nolabel="1"
                                   context="{'default_product_tmpl_id': active_id}">
                                <tree create="true" editable="bottom">
                                    <field name="sequence" widget="handle" readonly="0"/>
                                    <field name="name" readonly="0"/>
                                    <field name="image" widget="image" class="oe_left oe_avatar" readonly="0"/>
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                        </group>
                    </div>
                </xpath>
            </field>
```

Answer (score 1):

Masood Azhar

Use the `kanban` view instead of the `tree` view on this field `product_image_360_ids` and format the kanban view according to your design it will work for you.

```
<field name="product_image_360_ids" nolabel="1" context="{'default_product_tmpl_id': active_id}">
    <kanban class="o_kanban_mobile">
        <!-- Design your customise template here -->
    </kanban>
</field>
```

Thanks

Comment: it worked but it has created some issues.

1. Now when I am creating a record it shows my many2one field on the view: 
product_tmpl_id = fields . Many2one ( 'product.template' , string = 'Related Product' , copy = True )


I have tried to make it invisible by the attribute invisible = true in python. Also, that field was not in my view so I explicitly included that field in the view and tried invisible = true in XML as well but it didn't work either and the relational field is visible on creating the record.

Comment: 2. The other is that when I am selecting the image the image doesn't show up after selecting but it only shows up after I save the record (it was not in the case in tree view)

Comment: 3. There is no way to delete a kanban, if I mistakenly save a record there is no way to delete that (like it shows in action or any other option)

Comment: resolved delete issue through this:

<kanban  delete="true">
.
.
.
<a t-if="! read_only_mode" type="delete" style="position: absolute; right: 0; padding: 4px; diplay: inline-block">X</a>